# Easy way to Arabic word to English in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to change a sentence, for example :

> مرحبا

Would become :

> Marhaba

or I want to change a sentence, for example :

> kon'nichiha

Would become :

> kon nichiha

Is there any easy way to do this in obj c?

Comment: You need to use localized string

Comment: Use `NSlocalizedString` http://nshipster.com/nslocalizedstring/

Comment: Please help me to give some explanation. I don't understand how to use NSlocalizedString. @LeXeR

Comment: Saad check my answer

Answer (score 1):

I created the sample project and tried to get the solution for your question.I got it superbly.It works fine.I use **Go** English language and it converts to Arabic Language **اذهب**.

**FIRST STEP : Add the Arabic language in Localization of 
Info(Project->Info->Localization)**

```
Click Project
Then click Info
Then expand Localization.
Finally click + now choose Arabic
```

[image]

**Bellow localizations you can see the + now click the +.Once you click that it shows pop up box and choose Arabic from that**

[image]

**SECOND STEP : Create the Localization string file**

```
Create New File - iOS ->Resource->Strings File
```

[image]

```
Then Click Next now give File name.
So now it seems to be FileName.strings(Arabic)
```

**THIRD STEP : Click File Inspector when Localization string file is selecting  **

```
Click Localization
```

[image]

```
There is 3 boxes are there 
Base,English,Arbic with Empty checkbox(By default the Base Checkbox is checked)
see the below checkboxes.
```

[image]

```
Now click Arabic and English checkboxes
```

[image]

The Arabic Localization file looks like below

[image]

I create the Header file for the Localization Language.

[image]

The Header file above name is - LanguageHeader

Now I set English and Arabic in the LanguageHeader file

[image]

Before we go coding,I want to show my Storyboard design

[image]

Finally the code is below

First the Localization class of NSObject class

Localization.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "LanguageHeader.h"

@interface Localization : NSObject
+(Localization *)sharedInstance;
+(NSString*) strSelectLanguage:(int)curLang;
+(NSString*) languageSelectedStringForKey:(NSString*) key;

@end
```

Localization.m

#import "Localization.h"
    int currentLanguage,selectedrow;
    @implementation Localization

```
+(Localization *)sharedInstance
{
    static Localization *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[Localization alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}


+(NSString*) strSelectLanguage:(int)curLang{
    if(curLang==ARABIC){
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ar", nil]forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    }
    else{
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil]forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    currentLanguage=curLang;
    NSString *strLangSelect = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"] objectAtIndex:0];
    return strLangSelect;
}

+(NSString*) languageSelectedStringForKey:(NSString*) key
{
    NSString *path;
    NSString *strSelectedLanguage = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"] objectAtIndex:0];
    //When we check with iPhone,iPad device it shows "en-US".So we need to change it to "en"
    strSelectedLanguage = [strSelectedLanguage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"en-US" withString:@"en"];
    if([strSelectedLanguage isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"en"]]){
        currentLanguage=ENGLISH;
        selectedrow=ENGLISH;
        path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"];
    }
    else{
        currentLanguage=ARABIC;
        selectedrow=ARABIC;
        path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ar" ofType:@"lproj"];
    }
    NSBundle* languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
    NSString* str=[languageBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:@"LocalizationArabic"];
    return str;
}

@end
```

Then ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Localization.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    Localization *localization;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblGo;

- (IBAction)actionChangeLanguageToArabic:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize lblGo;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    localization = [Localization sharedInstance];
    lblGo.text = [Localization languageSelectedStringForKey:@"Go"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)actionChangeLanguageToArabic:(id)sender {
    [Localization strSelectLanguage:ARABIC];
    lblGo.text = [Localization languageSelectedStringForKey:@"Go"];
}

@end
```

When I run the app,first it shows in English

[image]

Now If I click the button action for changing language to Arabic

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not provide any such framework to translate a sentence like this.
You can translate using other web services such as

1. https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started

2.https://www.raywenderlich.com/1448/google-translate-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-translate-text-with-google-translate-and-json-on-the-iphone

3.http://www.tolq.com/?gclid=CjwKEAjw_LG8BRDb1JTxm8uP_UwSJADu_8pWDDVhroR2IvjRX1s1doXmgiDV20co_Mdp8xmcrVDGdhoCzdXw_wcB.

Comment: It's not translator, it's transliteration. see [Transliteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration)